# why couldnt achieve shared resource in python for twice(thread,timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, wxpython

this whole script depreciate the NMEA code that i take from serial port. and gave this error(actually give neither error nor desired :

```
A:    b'NX,1,1,2POTR1.01\n'
B:    b'NX0110,WVR=P 0*6\r$GTT000,RVE=80*1\r$NTT1002GSGLGALBS7\n'
B:    b'NX,1,2,BS;IS;S4\n'
A:    b'GX,0,1,,P;O;;D*7\r$GTT0,010SAMEQZS*9\r$GTT0002GSST=PSO*7\r\n'
A:    b'X,0012LL=FFFFFFFF-FFF-FFF-FFFF\x00*2\n'
B:    b'NX,1,1,,N OPG;GL3$GNTT1,,0,CFFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF\r$GX,1,,0,ANSPV=  DS SE\n'
B:    b'GT,0,10,NSTTU=O*25\n'
B:    b'$NX,012,F3F4B\n'
```

The code:

```
from threading import Thread
import serial
import time


def runA():
    while True:
        for line in ser:
            print("A: ",line)


def runB():
    while True:
        for line in ser:
            print("B:   ",line)
        print("hey")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ser=serial.Serial('COM9',9600)
    t1 = Thread(target = runA)
    t2 = Thread(target = runB)
    t1.setDaemon(True) 
    t2.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    while True:
        pass
```

expected is:

```
b'$GNGNS,080647.00,4059.11284,N,02907.92374,E,AA,13,0.84,130.5,37.5,,*6C\r\n'
b'$GNGGA,080647.00,4059.11284,N,02907.92374,E,1,12,0.84,130.5,M,37.5,M,,*47\r\n'
b'$GNGSA,A,3,09,22,01,11,17,18,23,03,31,,,,1.51,0.84,1.25*14\r\n'
b'$GNGSA,A,3,81,76,82,67,,,,,,,,,1.51,0.84,1.25*10\r\n'
b'$GPGSV,4,1,13,01,57,177,31,03,72,351,24,06,05,322,,09,24,241,30*72\r\n'
b'$GPGSV,4,2,13,11,28,189,17,14,14,052,,17,23,281,19,18,28,161,22*77\r\n'
```

I couldnt get data from same resource. Normally i know how to run two loops simultaneously but why didn't it work properly for this?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

there are a bunch of problems with this ... its not starved for resources ...

probably the main one is though that

`for line in serialPort` is not part of the serial interface

I think you mean to do

`for line in iter(ser.readline,''):` which will blockingly wait for a newline

but i expect you will get garbled output trying to consume from the same port in both threads ... but it wont block

this assumes that you can even access `ser` inside of your functions ... since its scope is the `if __name__ == "__main__"` and i think python3 fixes some leaky scope issues

I actually am pretty sure both your threads are just crashing out... and your main loop is just spinning

Comment: def runA():
        ser=serial.Serial('COM9',9600)

        while True:
       
            for line in iter(ser.readline,''):
                print("A: ",line)
            
    runA()          this works. ı dont have any problem with serial, my problem is using shared resource with thread. Thanks for your effort btw

Comment: your code is doing `for line in ser` ... not what I put, or what you put ... you need to do `for line in iter(ser.readline,''):` ...